# apache-cassandra : Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, cassandra

I was trying to startup cassandra on my system.I am getting the following error.It looks like it is missing some java packages,but I am not sure.

```
Starting cassandra
1 instance of cassandra running
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap$1.next(LinkedHashMultimap.java:545)
    at com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap$1.next(LinkedHashMultimap.java:533)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at java.util.Collections.max(Collections.java:735)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.printRing(NodeCmd.java:224)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.main(NodeCmd.java:1090)
```

How can I fix this issue.Maybe I need to install some java packages?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and the version of cassandra that I am using is apache-cassandra - 1.2.6

Comment: Add the OS name and versin and the exact steps that you took to start cassandra up. Also name the Cassandra version.

Comment: curious- did you download it from the apache site.  Have you tried downloading again or a different version (I'm able to run cassandra from the apache site on ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: maybe my system is missing some java packages.??

Comment: No, this exception is not about missing libraries. It looks like the code is trying to look up a node that is stored in a collection (LinkedHashMultiMap) but cannot find the element.. Could you say more about your cluster set up?